# Script Link in Header - EnableOptimizations Strips Attributes

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Not sure if this is a bug or if 2sxc is doing this on purpose, "for reasons."

First, here is the goal. I am in a 2sxc App, in a View using Razor/C#. I need to get the following JS module linked up in the <head> like this:

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/@dnncommunity/dnn-elements/dist/dnn/dnn.esm.js" 
  type="module" async="async" defer="defer" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Obviously if I just put it in as-is, it gets on the page, but not in the <head>.

If I add the attribute, `data-enableoptimizations="true"` then its in the <head> but all 4 of my attributes get stripped:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@dnncommunity/dnn-elements/dist/dnn/dnn.esm.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Additionally, notice that the src had only the leading "//unpkg...", and for some reason, the optimizations have added back "https:" which I do not want.

And where did `type="text/javascript"` come from? That hasn't been required for years.

I can solve this in the theme/skin by using the DnnJsInclude control like this. It uses ClientResourceManagement and allows me to specify all the attributes in HtmlAttributesAsString like this:

```
<dnn:DnnJsInclude
  FilePath="//unpkg.com/@dnncommunity/dnn-elements/dist/esm/dnn.js"
  ForceProvider="DnnPageHeaderProvider"
  HtmlAttributesAsString="type:module,async:async,defer:defer,crossorigin:anonymous" 
  Priority="1001"
  runat="server"
/>
```

This gets me the correct result, but it means my standard content editors now need the ability to edit page settings to use my 2sxc App. Which I do not want (the permissions or the training complication).

I realize I can probably use that DnnJsInclude control from my Razor code, but it seems like this is a valid use case that `data-enableoptimizations` should handle. Yes? No? Maybe? Maybe it already does it but I don't know the right syntax?

Anyone know how to get 2sxc to do this? Or is this a bug worth reporting regarding `data-enableoptimizations`? I was especially surprised that it just stripped my valid attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I worked it out in code using the DnnJsInclude control. Here is the solution in a nutshell:

```
@using DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement

@{
  // Add a <script> tag in the head as a JS module
  var include = new DnnJsInclude 
  {
    FilePath = "https://unpkg.com/@dnncommunity/dnn-elements/dist/dnn/dnn.esm.js", 
    ForceProvider = "DnnPageHeaderProvider",
    Priority = 1001, // stay out of the way?
    HtmlAttributesAsString = "type:module,async:async,defer:defer,crossorigin:anonymous",
  };
  var loader = (Context.CurrentHandler as Page).FindControl("ClientResourceIncludes");
  if (loader != null)
  {
    loader.Controls.Add(include);
  }  
}
```

Which gets the exact output needed thanks to the `HtmlAttributesAsString` parameter.

I even wrote it up as a blog post with a lot of details.

[DNN Details 004: Using the New Dnn-Elements in a 2sxc View?](https://dnncommunity.org/blogs/Post/12141)

Since this is dependent on Dnn, it doesn't benefit the Oqtane/hybrid coders.

Answer (score 0):

So for some background: once the attribute is set, it will be picked up and taken apart, because DNN will need the parts given one by one, not as a `<script>` tag.

I would assume that as of now, there is no mechanism which tries to preserve the remaining bits. We haven't looked at this in a long time, and maybe the DNN APIs are missing in v7.4.2 (our minimum compatibility).

But in general: this is currently by design, and could be improved. I suggest you open an issue on github and/or contribute a change ;)